# Rprofile.site can't work

Tags: r, rprofile

my system :debian
in console:
nano   /home/tiger/R-2.15.1/etc/Rprofile.site
here is my content:

```
.First <- function(){    
     cat("\nWelcome at", date(), "\n")
     }

.Last <- function(){
    cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
    }
```

when i save it ,reopen my  R ,
why there is no
Welcome at Sun Jul 15 07:53:58 2012
in my  R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check which files are being read.  Works here via `~/.Rprofile`. Using

```
edd@max:~$ tail -4 .Rprofile

.First <- function(){
    cat("\nWelcome at", date(), "\n")
}
```

gets the welcome message out:

```
edd@max:~$ R -q

Welcome at Sat Jul 14 20:36:57 2012 
R>
```

Comment: i made tries in window+R and debian+R:     
1.window +R:            
place : c:/R/r-2.15.1/etc/Rprofile.site         

when i open R,i can get Welcome at data()     
when i close R,nothing to happen      

2. debian+R:    
whether open or close R,nothing happen.

Comment: Re-read the introductory manuals (eg R Installation). Re-read `help(Startup)`.  This *not* rocket science, and `~/.Rprofile` is a simple shorthand for `/home/$USER/.Rprofile` where `$USER` is your login.